# std::array unique constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time

I want to remove duplicates from a `constexpr std::array` at compile time.

Basically, I'm trying to implement a `consteval` function, which returns a copy of the original array without duplicates:

```
consteval auto unique(std::array<...>) -> std::array<...>
```

I know `std::sort` is constexpr, so I thought I could first sort it first, with the intention of using `std::unique` next, but then I can't quite figure out how to make that work, there might be a better way than that.

Comment: Why do you have to do it at compile-time? What is the original problem you need to solve? What is the contents of your array? How many elements are there in it? Is `std::array` really the correct container to begin with?

Comment: Please provide full specification of `unique` possibly by using unit tests. What exactly should happen when duplicates are found? Should  return type change too?

Comment: Sorry - maybe my dupe hammer was wielded a bit hastily. Linked dupe only checks *if* there are dupes, not how to remove them.

Comment: also `consteval` suggest C++20. Is this a minimum C++ standard? Please clearly specify that (add tag).

Comment: ...feel free to hammer open or ping me to do so, if the answers in the linked target don't help.

Comment: I doubt if you can declare the size of the array in the return value. I have a solution, but it is not satisfying, because I also returned the new length which has to be taken into account for the real result, but it is done as consteval: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc78a43bea92f907